# funds/gemachs for baalei teshuvah

Tags: jewish-books, tefilin, tzitzis, baal-teshuva, chesed-kindness

Hey does anyone know of funds/gemachs for baalei teshuvah looking to purchase things such as tzitzis, tefillin, seforim etc? Maybe some baalei Chesed that may be able to help. If able to share would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MY, I think this is an interesting question/idea. I would recommend simply googling "gemach list [my city]" and start from there, if you haven't already.

Comment: https://chaburah.org/

Comment: Speak with Chabad, they have a fund in some locations for this sort of things. I know of one person who received tefilin from them

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: You need to join a community and engage with them; they may have resources for you. If you're doing this in total isolation, it's going to be very hard (and undesirable) to get random Gemach.com to give you stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Please send me an email if you need Tzitzis. Tzitiseliezer@gmail.com

Comment: Any chance you would happen to know anyone that may be able to help purchase tefillin?