# Tefillin fund for bale teshuvah

Tags: tefilin, chesed-kindness

I'm a baal teshuvah looking to purchase a pair of tefillin, any chance people may know where I may able able to purchase for a subsidized price by any chance? On a very tight budget!

Comment: Try your local Chabad-Lubavitch, or your local Orthodox community in general. This will be best handled at the local level.

Comment: A wider scoped similar question, asked by the same user less than a month ago: "[funds/gemachs for baalei teshuvah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/134866/1368)"